# Access Violation while calling a c++ dll function in C#

Tags: c#, c++, access-violation

System Access violation error occurs when a call to one of the C++ dll functions is made.
(Refer the code below  -  In the step int calresult =...i.e.,)
The array values are all appropriately given.
What part of the input might be causing this error?

Thanks !

C++ code-xyz.dll:

```
typedef struct model_parameters_t
{
    uint16_t *Input4;
    uint16_t *Input5;
} ;

typedef struct calibration_set_s
{
    uint16_t *input1;
    uint16_t *input2;
    uint16_t input3;
    model_parameters_t model;
} calibration_t;



extern "C"
{
    uint16_t compute(calibration_t);
}
```

C# code:

```
public struct model_parameters_t
{
    uint16_t [] Input4;
    uint16_t [] Input5;
} ;

public struct calibration_set_s
{
    uint16_t []input1;
    uint16_t []input2;
    uint16_t input3;
    model_parameters_t model;
} calibration_t;


[DllImport(@"xyz.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int compute(calibration_set_s calibration_set_t);



public class trycompute
{
    calibration_set_s calibration_set_Cal_input = new calibration_set_s();
    calibration_set_Cal_input.input1= array;
    calibration_set_Cal_input.input2= array;
    calibration_set_Cal_input.input3= 12;
    calibration_set_Cal_input.model.input4 = array;
    calibration_set_Cal_input.model.input5 = array;

    int CalResult = computeHybridCalCoeffs(calibration_set_Cal_input);
}
```

Comment: please add stacktrace

Comment: Your C# code has `typedef struct` in it.

Comment: Introduce the problem before you write any code. Please refer to this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the suggestion. I made appropriate changes.

Comment: @chris Thanks for pointing it out. I entered it by mistake.

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi Thanks for the comment. I am new to C#. can you let me know how to add stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Use actual pointers instead of arrays inside the structs in C#, declaring the class `unsafe`.

There is no way for C# to know how to marshal the arrays inside struct, for example, the size of arrays is undefined.

Comment: I pass the arrays of definite size in the steps calibration_set_Cal_input.input1= array; For eg.: calibration_set_Cal_input.model.input4 = new UInt16[width * height];

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.

I had to create a wrapper in C++/CLI around my native C++ dll. I then called the functions in the wrapper from my C# code. This solved the issue.